# Ion-select not working

Tags: typescript, ionic3, angular5

I'm using Ionic 3, i want to implement an `ion-select`, i followed the ionic docs, but i can't understand my mistake. My code here.

```
hosts: any[] = [
   '*MANAGER*',
   'Alberto Bellesini',
   'Alessandro Rodeghero',
   'Andrea Burla',
   ..............
];
```

In my html i have

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedHost">
    <ion-label>From:</ion-label>
    <ion-option *ngFor="let host of hosts" [value]="host"></ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

It does't work. I can see a number of radios equal to the length of my array, but all elements seems to be null or undefined: i can't see anything. I've already tried to make `hosts` as an array of strings but the result is the same. Could someone help me here?

Comment: Maybe there is a limit for the length of the array? Because I've got 30 elements

Comment: `hosts: any[] = ['*MANAGER*', 'Alberto Bellesini']`  is awful code. Please don't write that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just can't see a label for the radio buttons?

```
<ion-option *ngFor="let host of hosts" [value]="host">{{host}}</ion-option>
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: This is right, i forgot to add {{ host }}, moreover I had a override in my .css too, so I couldn't see nothing.